# Syntax Highlighting not working properly

Tags: c#, winforms, syntax-highlighting

So, I've been working on a Script Editor in C# in Visual Studio 2013 and of course I want to have syntax highlighting as a feature.
I have the following code:

```
programTextBox.Enabled = false;
Regex cKeyWords = new Regex("(auto|break|case|char|const|continue|defaut|double|else|enum|extern|float|for|goto|if|int" +
                            "|long|register|return|short|signed|sizeof|static|struct|switch|typedef|union|unsigned|void|volatile|while)");
int selectStart = this.programTextBox.SelectionStart;
int programCurrentLine = programTextBox.GetLineFromCharIndex(programTextBox.SelectionStart);
MatchCollection matches = cKeyWords.Matches(programTextBox.Lines[programCurrentLine].ToString());
foreach (Match match in matches)
{
   programTextBox.Select(match.Index, match.Length);
   programTextBox.SelectionColor = Color.Blue;
}
programTextBox.Select(selectStart, 0);
programTextBox.SelectionColor = Color.Black;
programTextBox.Enabled = true;
```

So, what does it do? It searches for some specific words in the current line. And form my tests I can tell that it can actually find those words in a matter of milliseconds.

But it doesn't really work. After it finds a match it changes the color of the first line. What I mean? Here is an example. Let'say that I use my Script Editor to write this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    ...
}
```

In this code, int is a keyword, so it must become Blue. However, the first three letters of the first line become Blue. I should also mention that it this example int is at the beginning of the second line, which is why the first three characters of the first line changed.

So, my code can find the keywords and can find their position, but instead of changing the color of these words, it applies the changes on the first line.

Can someone offer a solution?

EDIT: I found a way to fix this. Simply check my answer below.

Comment: Match.Index is wrong, that's the index of the word in the *single* line you regex.  You must add the index of the line you are parsing.

Comment: Also, parsing using regex isn't really what you should do. Use a parser/lexer, like ANTLR.

Comment: @HansPassant How am I supposed to this exactly? I tried replacing match.Index with programTextBox.GetFirstCharIndexOfCurrentLine(). However, it only highlights the first keyword of each line. If the same line has more than one keyword, then the rest of them will not have their color changed.

Comment: @HansPassant Just tried it. And I got this: 'System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox' does not contain a definition for 'GetCharIndexFromLine' and no extension method 'GetCharIndexFromLine' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?). It doesn't seem to work with a richtextbox.

Comment: Why not use one of the many highlighting text editors that are already out there? Like http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/161871/Fast-Colored-TextBox-for-syntax-highlighting or http://avalonedit.net/ ?

Comment: Pass *programCurrentLine* instead.

Comment: @PatrickHofman Well, I actually managed to fix my code and It's actually pretty fast since it can handle files with thousands of lines with ease because it only scans the current line, so what would be the benefit of a parser/lexer?

Comment: @RonBeyer Sure, I could, but sometimes making stuff on your own and figuring out why it doesn't work is fun and can help you learn new stuff!

Comment: You can't easily determine if a text is a keyword or contained in a string for example. A parser/lexer can handle those situations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Soo, I actually found a way to solve this!

```
foreach (Match match in matches)
{
    programTextBox.Select(programTextBox.GetFirstCharIndexOfCurrentLine() + match.Index, match.Length);
    programTextBox.SelectionColor = Color.Blue;
}
```

(The rest of the code is actually the same.)

Hans Passant was actually right, match.Index was causing the problem. After playing around and with some help from the comments I found out that using *programTextBox.GetFirstCharIndexOfCurrentLine() + match.Index* solves the problem.

Why? with *programTextBox.GetFirstCharIndexOfCurrentLine()* I can know in which line I have to alter the color and with *match.Index* I can know where in the current line is the found keyword.

Anyway, I would like to thank you Hans Passant, since your suggestions actually gave me this idea!